# How to enter Compress PDF file as attachments in ms dynamics crm 2011?

Tags: c#, pdf, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working for a client, and the client has a requirement to upload 6MB files in MS Dynamics CRM. Client having .pdf, .csv file to upload in Dynamics CRM. Now if we can compress these files before uploading to Dynamics CRM that will work fine. 
I am trying to fix the requirement by using below code.
This is working and compressing file but when we are downloading the attachment at that moment we are able to see the message as pop up

> We cannot open this file xxx.pdf file, because we found a problem
>   with its content.

```html
    if (entity.Attributes.Contains("documentbody"))
                {
                    string bytes = entity.Attributes["documentbody"].ToString();
                    tracingService.Trace("CompressImagePlugin: {0}", "crossed try block first line " + bytes.Length);
                    byte[] Uncompressedtext = Convert.FromBase64String(bytes);
    
    
                    if (entity.Attributes.Contains("filename") && entity.Attributes["filename"] != null
                                                               && (entity.Attributes["filename"].ToString()
                                                                   .Contains(".pdf") || entity.Attributes["filename"].ToString()
                                                                      .Contains(".docx")))
                    {
                        tracingService.Trace(entity.Attributes["filename"].ToString());
                        byte[] compress = CompressZip(Uncompressedtext);
                        string compressedData = Convert.ToBase64String(compress);
                        entity.Attributes["documentbody"] = compressedData;
                    }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi I am using below given code but not getting attachment file in correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are changing the file type from a PDF to a ZIP, you'll need to update the filename and the mimetype of the attachment as well. Something like this:

```
entity.Attributes["filename"] = entity.Attributes["filename"].ToString().Replace(".pdf", ".zip");
entity.Attributes["mimetype"] = "application/zip";
```

Now when the user clicks the attachment, they should be prompted to download a ZIP file that contains the PDF file.